# Angularjs uib-datepicker-popup. Корректное отображение названия месяца

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-bootstrap

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/yyyy" datepicker-options="{minMode: 'month'}" datepicker-mode="'month'" is-open="open" datepicker-append-to-body="false" ng-click="open = !open">
```

В данный момент месяц отображается в таком формате: [image: uib-datepicker-popup]

Нужно чтобы писалось в формате "Январь", "Февраль", "Март" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Если не пугает патч исходного кода библиотеки (она уже не развивается), то можете добавить в массив `formatCodeToRegex` следующий объект:

```
{
  key: 'LLLL',
  regex: $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.STANDALONEMONTH.join('|'),
  apply: function(value) { this.month = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.STANDALONEMONTH.indexOf(value); },
  formatter: function(date) { return dateFilter(date, 'LLLL'); }
},
```

И использовать в параметрах `'LLLL'`